# Railsでcarrierwaveを使ってAWS S3に画像をアップロードする手順

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

お世話になります。
Railsでcarrierwaveを使ってAWS S3に画像をアップロードする手順しているところで躓いたのでご教授いただきたいです。
https://qiita.com/junara/items/1899f23c091bcee3b058#s3%E3%83%90%E3%82%B1%E3%83%83%E3%83%88%E4%BD%9C%E6%88%90

**前提**

- railsインストール済
- AWSアカウント作成済み
- EC2にデプロイ済み
- S3バケットを作成済み

**解決したいこと**
photoモデルを追加して、imageカラムを設定した後の

```
rake db:migrate？
rails db:migrate ?
Directly inheriting from ActiveRecord::Migration is not supported. Please specify the Rails release the migration was written for:
ActiveRecord::Migrationを直接継承することはサポートされていません。移行が書かれたRailsリリースを指定してください。
```

とエラーが表示される。

**自力で調べた内容**
Directly inheriting from ActiveRecord::Migration is not supportedで検索した。
https://qiita.com/baby-0105/items/184048e18a8b1de93a31

**仮説と検証作業の結果**
以下をしても解決しなかった。

```
$ rails db:migrate:reset
$ rails db:migrate
```

バージョンの違いでmigrateが出来ないことがあるのか？
ご教授いただきたいです。

①https://gyazo.com/477cef32b2d842fa0e6e3bffeb373048
②https://gyazo.com/a1a68a7984ba9c1a97c59d10c29325d2

```
% ruby -v
ruby 2.6.5p114 (2019-10-01 revision 67812) [x86_64-darwin19]
% rails -v
Rails 6.0.3.4
% gem -v
3.0.3
```

Answer (score 1):

https://gyazo.com/a1a68a7984ba9c1a97c59d10c29325d2 の

`class CreatePhotos < ActiveRecord::Migration` のところ、

って書けるのはRails4か5.0あたりまでだったとおもいます。

ここを

`class CreatePhotos < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]`

にしてみて再度 rails db:migrate 試すとよいとおもいます

Comment: 無事に、rails db:migrateできました。
本当にありがとうございました。